# mongodb add comment for entry best practices PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to add a comment to entries into mongodb.
This is what i have so far

```
$mongo = new Mongo();
$db = $mongo->comedy;
$collection = $db->cartoons;
$obj = array( 
    "title" => "football", array('comment' => 'my comment here'),
    "author" => "joe" 
);

$collection->insert($obj);
```

which produces this entry

```
{
 "_id": ObjectId("5059fd31ba76883414000001"),
 "title": "football",
 "0": {
     "comment": "my comment here"
},
 "author": "joe"
}
```

**my question** is this the best way to nest a comment under the entry "football"? or should i be going about it a different way?
this part doesnt seem correct

```
"0": {
     "comment": "my comment here"
}
```

**update**
from the example below, running this gave an error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method MongoDB::update()`

```
$mongo = new Mongo();
$db = $mongo->comedy;
$collection = $db->cartoons;

$mongo->comedy->update(array('title' => 'football'), array(
        '$push' => array('comments' => array('content' => 'Yo!', 'author' => $user_id))
));
```

then when i run it like

```
$mongo = new Mongo();
$db = $mongo->comedy;
$collection = $db->cartoons;
$obj = array(
    '$set' => array("title" => "football", "author" => "joe"), 
    '$push' => array('comments' => array('content' => 'Yo!'))
);
```

i get

```
{
 "_id": ObjectId("505a2493ba76883c08000007"),
 "title": "football",
 "0": {
     "$push": {
         "comments": {
             "content": "Yo!"
        }
    }
},
 "author": "joe"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very typical problem in MongoDB and as a noob it too got me once here is a good structure (you can Google this around):

```
{
    title: footbal,
    comments: [
        {content: '', author: ObjectId()},
        { // Next comment }
    ]
}
```

You can then `$push` to the comments field making all comments be sorted from newest to 
oldest.

As a word of caution: You might find this schema a bit restrictive on it's querying possibilities especially when you want to, in realtime, sort the comments a different way or pick out different types of comments. In this scenario you would use a separate collection to house the comments ideally.

### Edit

In PHP you would start off by inserting your document:

```
$mongo = new Mongo();
$db = $mongo->comedy;
$collection = $db->cartoons;
$obj = array( "title" => "football");
$collection->insert($obj);
```

And then when a new comment needs to be added just simply $push:

```
$mongo->comedy->update(array('title' => 'football'), array(
    '$push' => array('comments' => array('content' => 'Yo!', 'author' => $user_id))
));
```

And that's the simple method of doing it :)

### Edit again

```
$obj = array('$set' => array("title" => "football", "author" => "joe"), '$push' => array('comments' => array('content' => 'Yo!'))));
```

Comment: am i doing something wrong? this overwrote the entry, didnt append the comment `$collection->update(array('title' => 'football'), array(
    'comments' => array('$push' => array('content' => 'Yo!'))
));`

Comment: @tq Ok try that, here is the doc page for it: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24push

Comment: im still getting the `"0": {}` is this correct?  made revision to my question

Comment: @tq Nah your using the object all wrong hang on....but getting 0 for the thing is right, it is an array of coment objects

Comment: the new edit is resulting in this ` {
   "_id": ObjectId("505a2493ba76883c08000007"),
   "title": "football",
   "0": {
     "$push": {
       "comments": {
         "content": "Yo!"
      }
    }
  },
   "author": "joe"
} 
` should that `$push` be there? also, `$mongo->comedy->update` doesnt work, but this does ` $collection->update`

Comment: @tq Can you show the full function your are running? Obviously you are trying to use this someway that I dont understand the context of

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16895/discussion-between-t-q-and-sammaye)

Comment: @tq It is because, as I just remembered, Mongo cannot do a $push and $set in the same update. If you are setting the rest of the document as well on the first go then it is better to build the object manually and then just push it in. Then on each update you use $push to add a new comment